# WiFi not showing up in kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, wifi-driver

I am on a Macbook Air m2 and have decided to use UTM for Kali Linux. the installation was a Fine but the WiFi is not showing up ,Even if I right click

Edit:
Now the WiFi is showing up and the 2 interface do also show up but there are no available network on either of them the permanent mac address is 02:00:00:00:00:00

Comment: It is connected to wired network

Comment: Please add information to your original post using the [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1803310/edit) button, not in comments underneath. Did you install the correct drivers?

Comment: compact-wireless-2010-6-28.tar.bz2 did the job

Comment: but now the problem is that wifi is disconnected

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The real problem is that UTM(The VM) and any other VMs out there will not detect you internal WiFi adapter. You. have to buy an USB WiFi adapter/dongle. I bought TP-LINK TL-WN722N.
After Plugging the Dongle you have to configure it in the VM.

Comment: Why a down vote?